# How to filter list of objects returned from amazon s3 whose file name ends with .txt

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here I am able to get the list of objects from amazon s3 bucket:

```
var params = {Bucket: 'Grade'};
s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
    alert(data.contents.length); // here I am getting count.
}
```

This is returning me list of objects from Amazon s3 bucket. How to filter list of objects from the list?

Here I am trying to filter items based on the txt file name which is not working fine. I need to filter it first and then display the same in table.

```
var files = $([{  "Key": + ".txt" }])
    .filter(function (i, n) {
        return n.Key ===  + ".txt";
    });

alert(files.contents.length);
```

- I need only the items whose filename ends with txt.
- I need to skip the objects whose file name doesn't end with txt format.
- I need to filter those objects whose file name ends with txt and display in table.
- Table contains 5 columns, I need to display only those objects whose file name ends with .txt.
- We need to match the file name with txt.and then filter, I am using javascript to do it but I am not getting desired result.

How to achieve my requirement?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter by file extension in the callback function itself:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'Grade'
};

s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
        const textFiles = data.Contents.filter(function(file){
            return (file.Key.indexOf('.txt') > 0);
        });

        console.log(textFiles);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this can never work:

```
var files = $([{  "Key": + ".txt" }])
            .filter(function (i, n) {
                return n.Key ===  + ".txt";
            });

          alert(files.contents.length);
```

You do not need to set that many plus signs.
Leave out the `+` like this

```
var files = $([{  "Key": ".txt" }])
            .filter(function (i, n) {
                return n.Key === ".txt";
            });
```

That should work.

Comment: This is returning me wrong count..i have more files with txt but its not retrurning exact, i think its not filtering correctly

Comment: Can you give us a sample return from s3?